# Trouble with Lua TCP server when using loop to receive and send messages multiple times

Tags: sockets, tcp, lua, server, luasocket

I need a client and server to communicate through a socket. The client tells the server that it wants a specific message (through a string "arquivo") and gets the message that is supposed to be 10KB long. Both of them have to maintain the connection open in case the client wants to ask for the message again with that same string. I could implement that for 1 exchange, closing the connection. When I put in a while though, the server apparently sends the message but it never gets to the client, unless I close the terminal window where the client is running. I ran each in a separate terminal window and tested the client's code with a server that only transmits the message once and then closes the connection and the message came through. The problematic server code is as follows:

```
filename = "file10KB.txt"
file = assert(io.open(filename, "r"))
msg = file:read("*a")
file:close()

socket = require("socket")

host = "*"
port =  8080

print("Binding to host '" .. host .. "' and port " .. port .. "...")

server = assert(socket.bind(host, port))
server:setoption("reuseaddr", true)
ipaddress, socketport = server:getsockname()
assert(ipaddress, socketport)

print("Waiting connection from client on " .. ipaddress .. ":" .. socketport .. "...")

connection = assert(server:accept())
connection:setoption("keepalive", true)
connection:settimeout(10)

print("Connected!")

while true do
    print("Waiting for request...")
    data, errormsg = connection:receive()

    if data == "arquivo" then
        print("Proper request received, sending message...")
        assert(connection:send(msg .. "\n"))
        print("Message sent!")
    elseif not errormsg then
        print("Invalid request.")
        break
    else
        print("Error message: " .. errormsg)
        break
    end
end
```

Also, my client's code:

```
socket = require("socket")

host = "localhost"
port = 8080

print("Attempting connection to server '" .. host .. "' and port " .. port .. "...")

client = assert(socket.connect(host, port))

client:setoption("keepalive", true)
client:setoption("reuseaddr", true)
client:settimeout(10)

print("Connected!")

repeat
    print("Sending message request...")
    assert(client:send("arquivo" .. "\n"))

    print("Message request sent! Waiting for message...")
    data, errormsg = client:receive("*a")

    if data then
        print("Message received!")
        print(data)
    else
        print("Failed to receive message.")
        break
    end
until not client
```

I'm new to Lua and to sockets and I followed some tutorials I found on the web, such as http://www.portugal-a-programar.pt/topic/36175-aprendendo-a-usar-lua-socket/ (it's in portuguese). I just hope any of you could shed a light on what I'm missing. I'm using Mac OS X machine by the way, don't know if that's any helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> When I put in a while though, the server apparently sends the message but it never gets to the client, unless I close the terminal window where the client is running

I don't know what this means. Closing the terminal window should close the client, which hardly means it will suddenly receive a message.

However there are numerous problems with this, too long for comments:

- You need to set SO_REUSEADDR *before* binding. Afterwards is too late.
- You don't need to set it at the client at all, but if you do it must be before connecting.
- The `sockname` check in the server is pointless. It can't fail.
- Your server only accepts one connection.
- Your server never closes the connection.
- Your server doesn't appear to recognized end of stream correctly.
- Your client never closes the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, I'll correct those. Also figured what my problem was, gonna respond the question below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the

```
data, errormsg = client:receive("*a")
```

line in the client's code. The option *a only receives when the connection is closed and changing it to *l or nothing like below made it work.

```
data, errormsg = client:receive()
```